# Implement Css and Js function on Custom Button in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am Trying to Create Custom Button in Ionic.

So, My Question Is I want to Implement Both CSS Method And Controller.js Function Method To my HTML File Class Button. How to add both Methods to button??

**Html File**

```
<div>
<button class="custom_btn"> 
</button>
```

**style.css File Code:**

```
.custom_btn {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

**Controller.js File Code**

in Controller.js File I am performing some Action on Button When it's Tapped

```
$scope.btnClicked = function()
{
//Perform some Action When it's Clicked
 }
```

Custom Button On Screen is displaying as per CSS Code but It's not Calling Function Method.Please Provide any solution.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to

```
<button class="custom_btn" onclick="whenButtonIsClicked()"> 
</button>
```

And your JS code to

```
function whenButtonIsClicked() {
//actions to perform
}
```

Explanation:
The onclick property of the button tells the whenButtonIsClicked() function to run when the button is clicked.
A framework is not necessary for this action.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Dah. Using **onclick** it was not working I changed with **ng-click** instead.And it is working Fine.Thanks for ur help!!